# Extracting specific points of a .txt in lazarus

Tags: lazarus

I have a textfile and I want to extract a specific value of it for example I have a line:

```
002345,6,7,8,9,10,25,
```

and I just want the values 7 9 and 25 to get extracted. I don't seem to find a way to get this working and I thought someone might be able to help me.
PS: I'm programming on Lazarus

Comment: Could you elaborate, eg, you mean you need 3º, 5º and 7º values of a comma-separated list of values?

Comment: yes that's what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code:

```
uses
  strutils;
var
  seq, v1, v2, v3: string;
begin
  seq := '002345,6,7,8,9,10,25,';
  v1 := ExtractWord(3, seq, [',']);
  v2 := ExtractWord(5, seq, [',']);
  v3 := ExtractWord(7, seq, [',']);
  writeln('3º: ', v1);
  writeln('5º: ', v2);
  writeln('7º: ', v3);
end.
```

will output:

```
3º: 7
5º: 9
7º: 25
```

Comment: Although this code is verbose to illustrate the solution it is affected by the [WET principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself#WET) which should be avoided - it just screams for using a loop.